# 'CheckTokenMembership' to check for Admin Rights C++

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

i'm trying to use the CheckTokenMembership function, i copied the example piece of code on Microsofts website ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa376389(v=vs.85).aspx ), but i just can't get it to work!

I get "error: 'CheckTokenMembership' was not declared in this scope" (on CodeBlocks) no matter what i do.

I am including Windows.h and even Winbase.h as the website says. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before including `windows.h` you need to specify the minimum version of Windows your application will support.  The idea here is that the build will fail if you use an API function that isn't available in the specified Windows version.

You can do this by defining the `_WIN32_WINNT` macro, e.g., for Windows 7:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7
```

If you need to be more specific you can also define the `NTDDI_VERSION` macro, e.g., for Windows 10 version 1607:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10
#define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_WIN10_RS1
```

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx) tends to lag behind, but you can find the definitions in `sdkddkver.h` in the SDK.

---

Addendum:

In some cases, e.g., if using an old or third-party version of the SDK, the named constants may not work and you will have to resort to magic values, e.g., the examples above would become

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
```

and

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x0A000002
```

You can look these up by obtaining a recent version of `sdkddkver.h` from Microsoft or you could try the search engine of your choice. :-)